# Weird behavior of generalized lambda function in C++14, while printing value of a 2-D array

Tags: c++, function, multidimensional-array, lambda, c++14

I was trying to build a sparse table to answer range queries and encountered this weird behavior of the lambda function, where the value of spt[1][0] is different when printed inside and outside of the g() function.
I noticed that if L is changed to some constant like 18, this code works fine.

Here is the code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n = 2;
    int L = ceil(log2(n))+1;
    int a[n] = {8,7}, spt[n][L];
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i)  
    {
        spt[i][0] = a[i];
    }
    auto g = [&]() {
        cout << spt[1][0] << '\n';
    };
    g();
    cout << spt[1][0] <<'\n';
}
```

Actual Output :

```
8
7
```

Expected Output :

```
7
7
```

Comment: Variable-length arrays `int n = 2; int arr[n]` is not a part of C++ standard. Also, a variable captured by a lambda cannot have a type involving a variable-length array.

Comment: `prog.cpp:8:11: error: variable-sized object may not be initialized
    int a[n] = {8,7}, spt[n][L];`

Comment: @S.M. I also took a[n] as input using for loop and still got the same output.

Comment: Not reproducible as is in the question after n and L replaced with 2.